# 'DecisionTree' object has no attribute 'criterion'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

There is an error  `'DecisionTree' object has no attribute 'criterion'`  in line `reg = GridSearchCV....`

The task is the following:

Using 5-fold cross-validation, find the optimal value for the `max_depth`  and `criterion`  parameters. For the `max_depth`  parameter use `range(2, 9)`  and for `criterion`  use `{'variance', 'mad_median'}` . Quality criterion `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'` .

```
class DecisionTree(BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(self, max_depth=np.inf, min_samples_split=2, 
                 criterion='gini', debug=False):
      params = {'max_depth':max_depth,
                 'min_samples_split':min_samples_split,
                 'criterion':criterion,
                 'debug':debug}
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        pass
        
    def predict(self, X):
        pass
        
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        pass


tree_params = {'max_depth': list(range(2,9)),
              'criterion':['variance','mad_median']}

reg = GridSearchCV(DecisionTree(), tree_params,
                  cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',n_jobs=8)

reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: it's literally what's the error is saying... https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html DecisionTree has no "criterion" attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its because the parameters in the constructor are not correctly initialized. You can add this line after your dictionary:

```
  for key, value in params.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

It will look like this:

```
class DecisionTree(BaseEstimator):

def __init__(self, max_depth=np.inf, min_samples_split=2, 
             criterion='gini', debug=False):
  params = {'max_depth':max_depth,
             'min_samples_split':min_samples_split,
             'criterion':criterion,
             'debug':debug}
  for key, value in params.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)

def fit(self, X, y):
    pass
    
def predict(self, X):
    pass
    
def predict_proba(self, X):
    pass
```

Or, the "usual" way:

```
class DecisionTree(BaseEstimator):

def __init__(self, max_depth=np.inf, min_samples_split=2, 
             criterion='gini', debug=False):
  self.max_depth = max_depth
  self.min_samples_split = min_samples_split
  self.criterion = criterion
  self.debug = debug
  
def fit(self, X, y):
    pass
    
def predict(self, X):
    pass
    
def predict_proba(self, X):
    pass
```